# What's the opposite sentence of "you have so much money"?

Tags: grammar, antonyms

What's the opposite sentence of "You have so much money"? Can I use "You have so little money"?

Or this: "You have so many hours to work", is using "You have so few hours to work" correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, “little” is the opposite of “much”, and “few” is the opposite of “many” (when they have these meanings).  “So” can modify any of those adjectives, so your sentences are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Those phrases are opposite:

much to little, many to few

So they are correct as opposite sentences.
You can check this [link](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/much_many.htm) for further information.